# How is natural log integration broken up into this range? (equation is contained the script)

Tags: integration, logarithms, natural-numbers

When I was reading a paper, I found an strange derivation like
$$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\mathrm{ln}(1+e^w)f(w)dw\\=\int^0_{-\infty}\ln(1+e^w)f(w)+\int^\infty_0[\ln(1+e^{-w})+w]f(w)dw$$
when $w$ is the normal random variable and $f(w)$ is the normal density.

Why is that natural log integration broken up into that?

I think it just need a simple principle.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$1+e^{-w}=1+\frac{1}{e^{w}}=\frac{1+e^{w}}{e^{w}}$.

Taking the ln, we obtain
$\ln(1+e^{-w})=\ln(\frac{1+e^{w}}{e^{w}})=\ln(1+e^{w})-\ln(e^{w})=\ln(1+e^{w})-w$

Therefore $\ln(1+e^{w})=\ln(1+e^{-w})+w$.

It follows that 
$\int_0^\infty \ln(1+e^{w}) f(w) dw =\int_0^\infty (\ln(1+e^{-w})+w) f(w) dw$.

Comment: That was very easy thing.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln(1+e^w)=\ln\left(e^w\left(e^{-w}+1\right)\right)=\ln\left(e^w\right)+\ln\left(1+e^{-w}\right) =  \ln\left(1+e^{-w}\right) +w $$

Comment: That was very easy thing.. Thank you so much!